# Facebook cookie not accessible to code

Tags: .net, asp.net, facebook

From yesterday we are facing a problem of my application keep on reloading in facebook.
I tried to debug it and came on following lines. Following is my code for facebook autologin.

```
 if ((Request["session"] != null) || (Request.Cookies[CookieName] != null))
        {

            Jayrock.Json.JsonObject objArray = new Jayrock.Json.JsonObject();
            if (Request["session"] != null)
            {
                string fbSession = Request["session"];
                fbSession = fbSession.Trim();
                objArray = (Jayrock.Json.JsonObject)Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.Import(fbSession);
                if (objArray != null)
                {
                    fbUserId = Convert.ToInt64(objArray["uid"].ToString());
                    fbSessionKey = objArray["session_key"].ToString();
                    if (objArray["access_token"] != null)
                        fbAccessToken = objArray["access_token"].ToString();
                }
            }

        if (fbUserId>0)
        {
           // redirect to application page
        }
        else
        {

            string URL1 = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + fb_APIKey + "&fbconnect=0&canvas=1&return_session=true&v=1.0";
           //redirect to url1

        }
    }
    else

    {
        string URL1 = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + fb_APIKey + "&fbconnect=0&canvas=1&return_session=true&v=1.0";
         //redirect to url1


    }
```

Problem which I am facing is that REQUEST['session'] is coming null in every case. I am facing this problem from yesterday only before that this application was working fine. Is there something from facebook side which changed yesterday because currently i am able to see requested data of fb users in cookie . But we are not able to access it from .NET.
I am new to .NET and got this code from some one but similar problem was there for our php application too and we updated our php sdk and problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Request.QueryString["session"]` instead of `Request["session"]`. Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Also try following:

```
string URL1 = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=" + fb_APIKey + "&fbconnect=0&canvas=1&return_session=true&v=1.0";
```